# Xamarin iOS "Walkthrough - Creating an application using the Elements API" Crashes

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to follow Xamarin's "[Walkthrough - Creating an application using the Elements API](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/elements_api_walkthrough/)" and my code crashes when I touch a "Task" which is supposed to launch a new screen to enter a description and date selector. The tasks appear when the NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem is clicked, but clicking on one of those causes the app to shut down in the simulator.

There's not much to the code, and I don't see where I went wrong.

Environment:
Visual Studio 2012 > Xamarin Build Host > Mac OS 10.9.5

The entire app is in AppDelegate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;

namespace ElementsApiWalkthrough
{
    public class Task
    {
        public Task(){}

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    }

    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow _window;
        RootElement _rootElement;
        DialogViewController _rootVC;
        UINavigationController _nav;
        UIBarButtonItem _addButton;
        int n;


        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            _window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            _rootElement = new RootElement("To Do List") { new Section() };

            // code to create screens with MT.D will go here …

            _rootVC = new DialogViewController(_rootElement);
            _nav = new UINavigationController(_rootVC);
            _window.RootViewController = _nav;
            _window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            _addButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
            _rootVC.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = _addButton;

            _addButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {

                ++n;

                var task = new Task { Name = "task " + n, DueDate = DateTime.Now };

                var taskElement = new RootElement(task.Name){
                    new Section () {
                            new EntryElement (task.Name, 
                                    "Enter task description", task.Description)
                    },
                    new Section () {
                            new DateElement ("Due Date", task.DueDate)
                    }
                };
                _rootElement[0].Add(taskElement);
            };


            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used the new iPhone project type.  Using an iPhone project from the "classic" templates fixed it.